# Object selection by tapping on it unity2d c#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game and there are two characters, Character 1 and Character 2. When i tap on a character that character should get selected(`selectedCharacter` variable should store the character's tag). I've tried this but it didn't work

```
public void Update()
{
    if ((Input.touchCount > 0) && (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began))
    {
        Ray raycast = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        RaycastHit raycastHit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(raycast, out raycastHit))
        {
            if (raycastHit.collider.CompareTag(tag))
            {
                data.selectedCharacter = tag;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note : My characters have 2Dcolliders and i also built the game and tried it on my android device.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're comparing the "tag".
From your text I thought you wanted to store the tag from the character that you selected?
If so then you can do:

```
if(Physics.Raycast(raycast, out raycastHit){
  data.selectedCharacter = raycastHit.transform.gameObject.tag;
}
```

If that wasn't what you meant then I don't understand your question.